# Sorting inputed numbers on array - Ruby - without using 'sort'

Tags: arrays, ruby, sorting, numbers, comparison

I would really appreciate it if someone can help me on this. 
I want to input numbers on this array x[0,100] 
Then, print the whole array but with the numbers inside sorted from the smallest to biggest WITHOUT using sort array.

I have this code so far, but I get an error where I do the comparison. Can someone help me on this please?

```
x = [0,100]
print x 

puts "\nInput any number from 0~100"
num = gets.to_i
x.push(num)

for i in 0..x.length-1
    for j in 0..x.length-1
        if x[j] < x[j+1] 
            swap = x[j]
            x[j] = x[j+1]
            x[j+1] = swap
        end
    end
end
p x
```

Comment: Is there any good reason you don't want to use standard API ? `WITHOUT using sort array`

Comment: My professor doesn't want us to use sort. I think it is because he want us to think our way around

Comment: You can swap in one line like this:` x[j], x[j+1] = x[j+1], x[j]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regardless of what the best solution would be, you get an error because your second loop is going out of bound: you're calling x[j+1] up to x.length-1, which means that you end up calling x[x.length] when the last element is x[x.length - 1].

Just replace "for j in 0..x.length-1" with "for j in 0..x.length-2"

```
x = [0,100]
print x

puts "\nInput any number from 0~100"
num = gets.to_i
x.push(num)

for i in 0..x.length-1
    for j in 0..x.length-2
        if x[j] < x[j+1]
            swap = x[j]
            x[j] = x[j+1]
            x[j+1] = swap
        end
    end
end
p x
```

Comment: Why are you doing `x = [0,100]` and `x = [1,49,20,30,58,10,48,9]` at the beginning of this script? Also, it's generally more Ruby-esque to use `each` instead of `for` loops :)

Comment: @DaniG2k Because that's what the OP wrote ;) I just copy/pasted the code of the OP with the correction, you should ask him/her

Comment: Oops that comment was meant for @basukesu not for you :P

Comment: oops! I am sorry. I was trying different things out before I posted my code, and I forgot to delete that useless array! Thank you for noticing @DaniG2k
I just deleted it but it will take some time for my edit to be processed :/

Answer (score 0):

Ruby ranges behave pretty much like arrays, at least when looping. They are already in order.

```
(1..100).each { |num| puts num }
```

Your code looks like it is looking if the next element is higher, then swipe. But what about more elements in the array? This is recursive way

```
def my_sort(list, new_array = nil)

  return new_array if list.size <= 0
  if new_array == nil
    new_array = []
  end
  min = list.min
  new_array << min
  list.delete(min)

  my_sort(list, new_array)

end

puts my_sort([3, 1, 2, 20, 11, 14, 3, 6, 8, 5])
```